# databind to particular element of array?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Assume my viewmodel contains property like:

```
public int[] GetConnectionsStats {
    get { return _stats; }
}
```

Now I want to databind textfield (one-way) to the first/second/third element of the returned array. Is it possible?

Of course I can always introduce `int GetFirstConnectionStats()` `int GetSecondConnectionStats()` etc. but I want to avoid that.

Comment: That ain't valid syntax, this is neither method nor property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same syntax as in C# given that you have a property:

```
{Binding GetSecondConnectionStats[1]}
```

If you have a method you could use the [`ObjectDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider.aspx), and take that as source:

```
{Binding [1], Source={StaticResource KeyOfObjectDataProviderDefinedAsResource}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try this:

If you have bound the text block to the _stats, You can acheive what you want by

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=stats[1]}/>
```